# Change chart size

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, size

I have created some charts in a loop that I'd like to display in one figure. The charts which I get are very small. So I've checked how to adjust the figure and found this function: plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)). The figure gets bigger indeed but the charts themselves remain with the same small size. How can I adjust the chartsize itself?

Comment: No, `figsize=(10,10)` will give you a bigger figure than usual. You can share a [mcve] of the code you use and explain clearly what problem you face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html

```
plt.subplots(left = 0.5, right = 0.8, bottom = 0.2, top = 0.9)
```

Fiddle with the parameters to learn what they do and how they're effecting your subplots.

Comment: I found this function plt.subplots_adjust() and it solved the problem. thx